# how to make a date picker that looks similar to a casino

Tags: javascript, html, css

Actually i just want to create a date picker that looks like a casino [something like this but it will be a date picker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JlPuB.jpg)
and i dont want the date picker to be a popup 
**any plugins in mind or tips on how to do that**
don't worry about closing the question, i will delete it when i am done
i have tried so many plugins, all to no avail
or does anyone have a demo code

Comment: Hello :) and welcome to StackOverflow. Please provide some code, people here will be rarely eager to provide a full solution from scratch ^^

Comment: @Y-BCause sorry, i'm new here

Comment: it's ok ^^ have a good day!